# Are general questions about OpenSSL output appropriate here? Or would that be more for serverfault / super user?

Tags: discussion, ssl

I'd like to better understand openSSL command output (for example, why intermediates appear to be shown in full but not the host-specific certificate).

Would this question be more appropriate for serverfault or superuser? I'm not experiencing an issue per-say, I just want to understand it better.

Comment: could you update this post with a little bit of your hypothetical question you'd like to ask, just to give it a more concrete example?

Answer (score 3):

I would say that if youre asking about the relevant *concepts*, this would be the best place to ask.
If you're asking about e.g. the formats, command parameters, etc - it would not be ontopic here, and I'm not too sure about SU either. Unless there is a specific difficulty, or some obscure setting....

Btw, same goes for openSSL API, for programmers - if its a question on the method, parameters, etc, it goes on SO - if its a higher-level question (e.g. which is the right algorithm, which padding, mode, etc) it belongs here.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think that's more on-topic over at serverfault, but you might be more likely to get better answers here. Therefore my suggestion would be to ask here, and if the community decides your question isn't relevant then one of us mods can always migrate the question later.

However, I'm only 33% of the mod community and my answer may not be binding :)

Comment: I'm another 33% and I agree with Graham - go for it. I would suggest making the question one which is answerable (check the FAQ for guidance) to help get more input.

Comment: Heh, neither is mine...